# Expand listview based on child count

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I need some help. I am trying to implement the Expandable list view. My problem is that when there are more than 2 children then only group must expand if not text view and button visible on the group layout. Please go through my code and the attached Image. The textview and button are visible when there are more than 2 children also.

[Screenshot of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVTnZ.png)

Menu.java

```
public class SubMenu extends BaseActivity {
String item;
ExpandableListView sec;
Toolbar carttoolbar;
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sub_menu);
    carttoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.carttoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(carttoolbar);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    String catname = getIntent().getStringExtra("CatName");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(catname);
    sec = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.seondlst);
    sec.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                sec.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
        }
    });
    Intent hello = getIntent();
    item = hello.getStringExtra("Catergory");
    loaditems();
}

private void loaditems() {
    String url = Constant.commonurlyell + "data_standard_item_ind_new.php?rname=standardtakeaway&id=" + item;
    Log.d("ITems", url);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    JsonObjectRequest arrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            ArrayList<Subitem_base> list = new ArrayList<Subitem_base>();
            ArrayList<Subitem_base_child> ch_list = new ArrayList<Subitem_base_child>();
            try {
                JSONArray itemsarray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                Map<Integer, ArrayList<Subitem_base_child>> ch_lists = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Subitem_base_child>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsarray.length(); i++) {
                    ch_list = new ArrayList<Subitem_base_child>();
                    JSONObject itemsobj = itemsarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Subitem_base subitem = new Subitem_base();
                    subitem.setGroupitemname(itemsobj.getString("BaseName"));
                    JSONArray subitemsarray=itemsobj.getJSONArray("subitems");
                    for (int j = 0; j <subitemsarray.length() ; j++) {
                        JSONObject subitemsobj=subitemsarray.getJSONObject(j);
                        Subitem_base_child subitembase=new Subitem_base_child();
                        subitembase.setChilditemname(subitemsobj.getString("SubItemdesc"));
                        String pricevalue = "£";
                        subitembase.setChilditemprice(pricevalue.concat(subitemsobj.getString("SubItemprice")));
                        ch_list.add(subitembase);
                    }
                    ch_lists.put(i, ch_list);
                    subitem.setItems(ch_lists.get(i));
                    list.add(subitem);

                }
                SubItem_ExpandAdapter subexpand = new SubItem_ExpandAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list,SubMenu.this);
                int childCount=sec.getChildCount();
                Log.d("Std", String.valueOf(childCount));
                sec.setAdapter(subexpand);
                subexpand.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.hide();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("SecondleveError", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    });
    arrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(arrayRequest);
}
```

}

MenuAdapter.java

```
public class SubItem_ExpandAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
Context subcontext;
private ArrayList<Subitem_base> subitem_bases;
private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
String itembasename, itemde, subtmsub, subitempri;
private Activity parentActivity;

public SubItem_ExpandAdapter(Context subcontext, ArrayList<Subitem_base> subitem_bases, Activity parentactivity) {
    this.subcontext = subcontext;
    this.subitem_bases = subitem_bases;
    this.parentActivity=parentactivity;
}

static class Groupname {
    private TextView group_name;
    private TextView groupitem_price;
    private Button grouporder;
    private ImageView droparrow;
}

static class Childnames {
    private TextView item_name;
    private TextView item_price;
    private Button order;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return subitem_bases.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Subitem_base_child> subitem_base_children = subitem_bases.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return subitem_base_children.size();
}


@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return subitem_bases.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Subitem_base_child> subitem_base_children = subitem_bases.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return subitem_base_children.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Groupname groupname;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(subcontext).inflate(R.layout.group_item, parent, false);
        groupname = new Groupname();
        groupname.group_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        groupname.groupitem_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupitem_price);
        groupname.grouporder = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grouporder);
        groupname.droparrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.droparrow);
        convertView.setTag(groupname);
    } else {
        groupname = (Groupname) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Subitem_base groupitem = subitem_bases.get(groupPosition);
    groupname.group_name.setText(groupitem.getGroupitemname());
    if (isExpanded){
        String[] elements = {groupitem.getGroupitemname() };
        for (String s: elements) {
            itembasename=s;
        }
    }
    if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition)>=2) {
        Log.d("Std", "called");
    }else {
        groupname.groupitem_price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        groupname.droparrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        groupname.grouporder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Childnames childname;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(subcontext).inflate(R.layout.child_item, parent, false);
        childname = new Childnames();
        childname.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        childname.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        childname.order = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order);
        convertView.setTag(childname);
    }else {
        childname= (Childnames) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Subitem_base_child childitem = (Subitem_base_child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (childitem.getChilditemname().isEmpty()){
        childname.item_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        childname.item_name.setText(childitem.getChilditemname());
    }
    childname.item_price.setText(childitem.getChilditemprice());
    loginPreferences = subcontext.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String status = loginPreferences.getString("Status", "");
    if (status.equals("0")) {
        childname.order.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cart_disable);
    }else {
        childname.order.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cart_button);
    }

    childname.order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status.equals("0")) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parentActivity);
                SharedPreferences customerid = subcontext.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String opentimes = customerid.getString("open", "");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(opentimes);
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else {
                String poundre = childname.item_price.getText().toString();
                subtmsub=childname.item_name.getText().toString();
                subitempri = poundre.replace("£", "");
                addcart();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
private void addcart(){
    loginPreferences = subcontext.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
    SharedPreferences customerid = subcontext.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPreferences.edit();
    String customid = customerid.getString("customerid", "");
    String cartdetails = itembasename + " " + subtmsub;
    String cartspacong = cartdetails.replace(" ", "$");
    cartspacong = cartspacong.replace("&", "and");
    String addcarturl = Constant.commonurltake + "cart_process.php?userid=" + customid + "&Item=" + cartspacong + "&Itemcount=1&price=" + subitempri + "&page=items";
    Log.d("Cart", addcarturl);
    JsonArrayRequest cartreq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, addcarturl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject cartobj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String cartnumber = cartobj.getString("count");
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString("Count", cartnumber);
                    BaseActivity.cartnumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    BaseActivity.cartnumber.setText(cartnumber);
                    loginPrefsEditor.apply();
                    if (cartobj.has("message")) {
                        Toast carttost = Toast.makeText(subcontext, cartobj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        carttost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        carttost.show();
                    } else {
                        Toast carttost = Toast.makeText(subcontext, "Product Added To Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        carttost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        carttost.show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(subcontext, "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    cartreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(cartreq);
}
```

}

Comment: You have simply posted your whole code. First try to debug and identify where the error is occurring and then post the relevant code only. That way, it will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please [create a minimum complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes i had done the value are coming twice in the loop